# W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(27114): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I've created a new app using the command pallet in vs Code, and I'm having many issues using it.

1. The inspector doesn't work - I get a message in the inspect window, stating that the inspector is not available for the application.
2. the application crashes a lot, and I have to wait a long time for rebuilding.
3. I get the following message in the debug console:

> Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
> lib\main.dart:1 √  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
> W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(27114): A splash screen was
> provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See
> flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
> Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:60885/Gjga6R7ZZ-o=/ws
> I/Choreographer(27114): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be
> doing too much work on its main thread.

I have a feeling that there's something wrong with my environment.

windows 10
vs code 1.60.2
fluter 2.5.2

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please provide the output of `flutter doctor --verbose`?

Comment: For the first time, it takes very long to build the app(for me it too 30 mins). After that it works correctly with lesser time.

Comment: Are you able to setup a new project with the flutter command line tool (`flutter create myapp`), and run it in the emulator from vscode?